# smart filter bar value help search

Tags: sapui5

In the following [Smart Filter Bar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar/preview) example when clicking on the Company Code value help, what is the purpose of the search field? It doesn't do anything when I am trying to use it. I am trying to implement similar in my app but it is not working either.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain this in terms of OData request.

If you enter "Value1" in the basic search field:

`search-focus=CompanyCode&search=Value1`

If you type "Value2" in the Company Code value help:

`$filter=(CompanyCode eq 'Value2')&search-focus=CompanyCode&search=`

If you enter values in both fields:

`$filter=(CompanyCode eq 'Value2')&search-focus=CompanyCode&search=Value1`

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah that helps. It is just strange that in their example provided by SAP in the "Explored" the search field is there but not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the so called "Basic Search Field"
The basic search field allows the user to filter the results by a given keyword.

Further information can be found here: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/filter-bar/#guidelines

Comment: I think basic search field is shown together with the filters on the filter bar. This one is on the Company Code value help level and it should filter out values in the table with company codes and names. I saw some FIORI apps doing it. It is not working in the above example and not working in my app so I am trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I would sugest to provide more information, in order to be able to investigate your issue...